# Exported configuration with drush cex only visible in docker shell, not in local repo

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I have a Drupal 8 local development environment running with [Docker](https://www.docker.com). I can use drush (use `drush cr`, `drush cex -y` etc) after I login with ssh in docker.

- I make some configuration changes in my Drupal admin. After that I want to export them to my config sync directory `configuration/base` (which is tracked by Git)
- I use `drush cex -y` to export my configuration. I get the message: `Configuration successfully exported to configuration/base`

But after a `git status` I don't see any changed files? Also when I look at my `yml-files` in my local git repo (in `configuration/base`), I don't my changed configuration? But when I look in the shell (from where I also use drush), I see my changed `yml-files`. But there my local git repo isn't tracking those files.

So what do I have to do, after I do a `drush cex -y`, to get my changed exported configuration visible in my local git repo?

Comment: That's probably off-topic. We'ld need to see at least your `docker-compose.yml`. Additional info about host and helper apps would help as well.